# How can I make vscode margins wider?

Tags: visual-studio-code, layout, editor

Currently this is what my vscode editor displays, where the text runs until the end of the page and I have to scroll right:

[image]

I'd like to make the margins wider so that I can see all the text like in here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Settings > Editor > Word Wrap*

set a custom width:

*Settings > Editor > Word Wrap Column*